# EJB QL data Syntax error

Tags: java, sql, ejb, ejbql

I am trying to retrieve all the entity from the TransactionE t entity where the month of t.purchasedDate is equal to the current month.

However, I encountered a syntax error when my code run.

```
String query = "SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE Month(t.purchaseDate) = Month(" + getCurrentDate()+")";

Query q = em.createQuery(query);
```

Any help please?

getCurrentDate() is a function that will return the date of current day in "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

The below is a query that I was hoping to achieve.
**SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE Month(t.purchaseDate) = Month("2013-10-06")**

Error :
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE Month(t.purchaseDate) = Month(getCurrentDate()), line 1, column 40: unexpected token [(].

Comment: try single quotation for date

Comment: Hi there, You mean something like this? 
SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE Month(t.purchaseDate) = Month('2013-10-09')

I just tried. Single quote did not work

Comment: Which application server are you using? Whic JPA library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`Month` not is a standard JPQL function. Try:

```
SELECT t 
  FROM TransactionE t 
 WHERE FUNC('MONTH', t.purchaseDate) = FUNC('MONTH', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: Hi. I tried and I got this error. Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT t FROM TransactionE t WHERE FUNC('MONTH', t.purchaseDate) = FUNC('MONTH', 2013-10-10)]